# Why is my javascript function not replaced by the new one?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the javascript function to be called once I have clicked on a button but it's still the old one that is called.

function called on first click : longueur()

function called on second click : tester()

html code :

```
<input id="entree" type="text" name="longueur" value="" /> 

<input id="bouton" type="submit" value="longueur du mot" onclick="longueur()" />
```

javascript :

```
function longueur() {
    let entree = document.getElementById("entree") ;
    let bouton = document.getElementById("bouton") ;
    ... 
    ...
    ...
    entree.name = "lettre" ;
    bouton.value = "Nouvelle lettre" ;


    bouton.onclick = "tester()" ;   

}
```

Why is it still longueur() that is called on the second click ?

Comment: You can do `bouton.setAttribute("onclick", "tester()");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#Syntax) attribute expects to receive a `function`, instead you are setting it with the **string** `"tester()"`. Check the next example showing a correct usage:

```js
function longueur()
{
    console.log("longueur called!")
    let bouton = document.getElementById("bouton") ;
    bouton.value = "Nouvelle lettre" ;
    bouton.onclick = tester;
}

function tester()
{
    console.log("tester called!");
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<input id="entree" type="text" name="longueur" value=""/> 
<input id="bouton" type="submit" value="longueur du mot" onclick="longueur()"/>
```

In the particular case that you need to pass arguments to the `tester()` method, you can proceed like on next sample, that uses an [anonymous function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)):

```
let arg1 = <some_value>;
let arg2 = <some_value>;
...
bouton.onclick = function() { tester(arg1, arg2); };
```